# Why does string concatenation with the + operator work with dynamic types in C#?

Tags: c#, string, dynamic, expression-trees, dynamic-language-runtime

I recently saw an example where the following was demonstrated to work:

```
T Add<T>(dynamic a, dynamic b)
{
    return a + b;
}

Add<string>("hello", "world");  // Returns "helloworld"
```

However, if I were to attempt to use expressions to create a "generic" Add function:

```
ParameterExpression left = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "left");
ParameterExpression right = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "right");
var add = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(Expression.Add(left, right), left, right).Compile();  // Fails with System.InvalidOperationException : The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.String' and 'System.String' when T == String.
```

and then used this function with strings, it fails because the String type does not actually implement the + operator, but is simply syntactic sugar for String.Concat().

How then, does dynamic allow this to work? I figured that at runtime it is past the point where + would be rewritten using String.Concat().

Comment: `"hello" + "world"` is `"helloworld"`, not `"hello world"`.

Comment: You're right.  I corrected it.

Comment: Hmm, my answer wasn't very relevant. Does the above `Add` method also work with delegate types? Like if you say `Action a = () => { Console.WriteLine("Hello"); };` and then say `var b = Add<Action>(a, a);` then what happens at runtime (and if the call succeeds, will `b();` work as expected afterwards?)?

Comment: Note that VB.NET uses `&` for concatenating, so that's why `Expression.Add` can't concat strings, as add represents universal `+`. DLR, on the other hand, knows about the actuals compiler and language it is used in, so it resolves `+` to either "add" or "concat".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dynamic` uses runtime helper functions that replicate C# compiler rules. One of these rules allows `+` on `string` objects even when no operator is defined by the framework. The standard numeric types such as `int` have no custom operator overload either, that too is done by the compiler and needs to be performed at runtime when using `dynamic`. This is why you need a reference to Microsoft.CSharp.dll: `dynamic` cannot work without those helper functions.

Comment: By looking at the generated IL and seeing what `dynamic` compiles to :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the documentation, maybe instead of `Expression.Add(left, right)` you could say `Expression.Add(left, right, method)` where `method` is the `MethodInfo` of the static `String.Concat(String, String)`.

```
var method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), });
```

**EDIT:** Hmm, my answer sort of misses the point. The interesting question is: What operations does the runtime consider when it tries to resolve a `+` that the compiler has let through without type-checking? Bulit-in addition for numeric types? String concatenation? Delegate concatenation? User-defined operator overloads?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example a and be are still strings (try this):

```
// Define other methods and classes here
T Add<T>(dynamic a, dynamic b)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine(b.GetType());
    return a + b;
}
```

Maybe this makes more sense?

```
void Main()
{
var x = Add<string>(new { val = "hello"},new { val = "world"});  // Returns "hello world"  
Console.WriteLine(x);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
T Add<T>(dynamic a, dynamic b)
{
    return a.val + b.val;
}
```

Comment: I know they are still strings, but I thought that using dynamic meant that the CLR did not know they were strings until runtime.

Comment: I believe dynamic only is dynamic for properties -- if the object is a type it does not lose the type.

Comment: @MattH: You misunderstood.  Being `dynamic` tells the compiler not to resolve anything until runtime. The decision to choose which methods to call are not actually checked until the expression involving the dynamic variables are reached.  At runtime, it was determined that both `a` and `b` are strings and there exists an operator overload for addition between two strings, hence the concatenation.

Comment: @MattH: Also, addition of strings is a special case to the compiler/runtime, there is no "real" operator overload for addition. There can't be otherwise the compiler wouldn't be able to _efficiently_ concatenate multiple string constants through a single call to `String.Concat()`.

Comment: I know String does not actually implement the + operator.  That's WHY the expression based code fails.  You seem to be contradicting yourself, however, by stating that there is an operator overload for String, but then saying there isn't one.

Comment: C# is still strongly typed.  All dynamic does is let you change the properties and what values they have.  Properties are not known at compile time -- but the type is always known in C#

Comment: Dynamic defers type checking until runtime, when there is no string + operator.

Comment: No.  That is wrong.  Dynamic does not defer type checking to run time.  It defers type checking of attributes to run time.  You were not using any attributes.

Comment: Sorry, Hogan, but I believe you are incorrect. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx

Comment: Point taken -- however, these dynamic/objects are still strings.  GetType() outputs string -- using `dynamic` in your example is no different than using `object`.

Comment: @Hogan With `object`, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: @hvd - conceptually hvd not actually - meant conceptually.

Comment: @Hogan Then your comment doesn't make sense to me. The concrete type is only known at runtime, so some time at runtime, the `+` operator is replaced by `String.Concat` (or some equivalent method). This question asks where and how that happens, if it's not done by the compiler.

Comment: It is done by the dynamic language runtime of course. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx

Comment: @Hogan Pretty much, yes, and that contradicts your earlier comments, which is why this went on longer than it should have.